# Projection or XYs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, xy, position

I am trying to project some data that I got. I have .txt files with XYs and they are correct, the problem that when I project the data, the points appearing in a different geographical location than the polygon map and they are distributed in a horizontal position instead of vertical as the shape of the map. Boths layers appears to be in the same projection,I am trying to change they but noting happens. I am sorry I do not know how to explain this problem much clear, and I do not know how to fix it either.

[image: As you can see in the image the two layers are not posisionated in the sample place (eve they have same coordinate system) and they points are horizontal...]

Comment: Screenshots would be helpful. What projection is your polygon layer in?

Comment: Please provide more detail (by editing your question, not as a comment) on the input data (current projection, output projection) and a sample preferably and how you are re-projecting the data.

Comment: What is the current projection? What is the output projection? I have a txt file and I just want to plot the point in the map... and they are horizontal instead of being vertical, I am sorry I do not know how to explain it better.

Comment: It sounds to me as if the x and y positions are switched.
Make certain that you choose the proper fields (columns) in the dialog box when importing the text file.

Comment: That happens often @jbgramm, especially if the X and Y columns are Lat and Lon, Lat expressed first and is taken as X and Lon therefore is Y, which is incorrect.. this diagram http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.1/general_topics/what_coord_sys.htm helps show that Lat,Lon is Y,X; conversely Easting, Northing, which is common in text files for projected data, is X,Y

Comment: Based upon the above screenshot, I would suggest switching the columns (fields) that are being chosen for the coordinates.
If the original columns were imported as X= Column 2, and Y = Column 3, try importing the file again using X= Column 3, and Y = Column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing a text file, QGIS asks you select fields to use for X and Y coordinates. If your data is Latitude and Longitude values, make sure to use

- X field: Longitude
- Y field: Latitude

In this example, the first row of my text file contains column headers, with one columns labeled "Latitude" and one column labeled "Longitude."

[image]

If your text file doesn't have a header row, uncheck the box next to "First record has field names." Assume your values are stored in this order: (Latitude, Longitude). Import the file with the first column as the Y field and the second column as the X field. If the points aren't in the right locations, remove the layer and re-import it with the fields reversed.

[image]